# Overriding resignFirstResponder fails

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchbar, resignfirstresponder

Trying to override resignFirstResponder methode of UISearchBar in order to make Cancel button always enabled:

```
@interface UISearchBar(alwaysEnableCancelButton)
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder;
@end

@implementation UISearchBar(alwaysEnableCancelButton)

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    // Force the cancel button to stay enabled
    UIView *possibleButton;
    for (possibleButton in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([possibleButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)possibleButton;
                [cancelButton setEnabled:YES];
        }


        // Dismiss the keyboard
        if ([possibleButton isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField *)possibleButton resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"done");
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

But the log shows nothing!

I'm using it like

```
[mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: did you #import the category?

Comment: Categories can't override methods.

Comment: Got it...renamed the method and it worked properly...where should I override methods like this? Thank you!

Comment: The proper solution would be to subclass `UISearchBar`. Then you can properly override the method. Then in your app you use your custom subclass instead of a straight `UISearchBar`.